# filter pyspark on multiple conditions using AND OR

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two columns in my df.i want to filter on these columns in such a way that the resulting df after the filter should be like the below resultant df.

input Table

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| null | Approved |
| FALSE | null |
| null | null |
| FALSE | Approved |
| TRUE | null |
| null | new |
| FALSE | Declined |
| FALSE | new |

output result Table after filter

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| null | Approved |
| null | null |
| **FALSE | Approved** |
| TRUE | null |
| null | new |

LOGIC - ****if col1 is False then col2 should be Approved****, OR col1 should not be equal to FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `where` on your `df`

```py
df.where("""
 (
    col1='FALSE' AND 
    col2='Approved'
 ) OR
 col1 <> 'FALSE'
""")
```

or

```py
df.where(
    (
        (df.col1 == 'FALSE') &
        (df.col2 == 'Approved')
    ) 
    | 
    (df.col1 != 'FALSE')
)
```

NB. we use `&` for `and` and `|` for `or`